# Difference between Spring TestContext Framework and Jboss Arquillian

Tags: unit-testing, spring, integration-testing

My company developed in the last 7 years a medium/large web application. The application make use of Spring Framework (3.0), Hibernate(3.x) and Struts (1.x) among the others. Unfortunately we didn't use any kind of automatic tests. Now we need to add them to avoid regression bug and to start a better development lifecycle. 
Following best practice for this hard job, I read we could start with smoke gui test, followed by integration testing before adding unit test.
So my question is: about integration test (in container) which are the difference between Spring TestContextFramework and JBoss Arquillian? I read Arquillian will support Spring in it's final release (http://community.jboss.org/message/563768). Will I have some kind of benefits using it once stable?

Thanks,
Stefano.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Arquillian, but it seems to be focused on EJB testing with emphasis on deploying to a live container. If your application is based on Spring (+ Hibernate), Spring Test support is probably the best choice.

Within the test case you can start part of your application context (only a small piece or almost a whole application) with mocked in-memory database. You don't need a running container, as Spring is mostly self-contained. Testing Struts 1.x actions is harder, but I guess Arquillian won't help you either.

Also if the software stability is your concern, Arquillian seems to be in Alpha version now. But I would definitely give it a chance it I would have to test EJB based application. For Spring application, with context caching, transaction demarcation in tests, etc. TestContext Framework is the best choice.

Side note: consider using TestNG instead of JUnit, as it plays much nicer with TestContext, e.g. you have access to Spring beans in setup/tear down methods (static in JUnit).

Comment: I agree with this answer. I haven't used Arquillian myself, but the idea of needing to deploy to container to run tests sounds pretty bad. As said, with Spring TestContext you can initialize your application, run a single test, do changes without need to redeploy (although you would probably need to re-start the TestContext). Also, I don't know what sorts of tests you are planning to run on Struts, but you can conveniently run Selenium tests against any web framework if functional tests are what you're after. You could also run Selenium through Spring TestContext to access the same DB :)

Comment: Of course, if using EJBs, you could also run something like OpenEJB to use the EJBs on tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Arquillian user myself, but I recommend you to stick with Spring's solution. While eventually it will be container agnostic, right now the effort is focused on Java EE. Your job seems hard enough and I wouldn't recommend Aquillian for now.

However, to clear up some confusion, you can run embedded tests on Arquillian. It can bootstrap an embedded Glassfish or JBoss AS servers and run test using the "real thing" instead of mock or alternate implementations. JPA, Interceptors, JTA, XA Datasources, JMS, JSF, Servlet. All available - batteries included ;)

Alternatively, you could fire up an JBoss instance on the background and run the test remotely. Arquillian takes care of the deploy/test/undeploy cycle - and it's blazing fast!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used either of them, but here's my sum up of the documentations:

**## Spring Integration Tests ##**

Spring allows to perform some integration tests **without requiring deployment to an application server**.

Spring's support for unit-testing **and** integration-testing is provided by *Spring TestContext Framework*, which is agnostic of the testing framework in use (JUnit, TestNG, etc.).

TestContext Framework provides:

- > consistent loading of Spring `ApplicationContext`s and `WebApplicationContext`s as well as caching of those contexts.
  >   [[1]](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-ctx-management)
- > optionally configures instances of your test classes via
  >   Dependency Injection. [[2]](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-fixture-di)
- provides transaction management for transaction tests: the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test.
- provides abstract classes, that can be extended by developers to easily code JUnit or TestNG test cases classes.

**## Arquillian ##**

Arquillian runs the integration tests **inside a real runtime environment**, whose life-cycle is managed by Arquillian. 
Indeed with Arquillian, your integration tests are either executed inside a **container**, or interact with a container as a client.

The container may be:

- an embedded or remote Servlet container (e.g., Tomcat, Jetty),
- a Java EE application server (e.g., GlassFish, JBoss AS, Embedded GlassFish),
- a Java SE CDI environment
- or any other container implementation provided

Arquillian :

- manages the lifecycle of the container (start/stop),
- bundles the test class with dependent classes and resources into a
  deployable archive,
- enhances the test class (e.g., resolving @Inject, @EJB and @Resource
  injections),
- deploys the archive to test (deploy/undeploy),
- captures results and failures.

**#How it works#**

Arquillian provides a custom test runner for JUnit and TestNG.

1. When you run your tests, this custom test runner will detect the `@RunWith Arquillian` declaration.
2. The custom test runner will thus turn control of the test execution lifecycle from the unit testing framework(JUnit or TestNG) to Arquillian.
3. For each test case:

   1. Arquillian will use ShrinkWrap to create "micro archives". The classpath control allowed by ShrinkWrap empowers Arquillian to declaratively define a custom Java EE archive, that encapsulats the test class and its dependent resources, but nothing more!  This gives you fine-grained control over what you are testing and what resources are available at the time the test is executed.
   2. Arquillian deploys each "micro archive" to the target container (which is configured in the maven profile), I assume one by one.
   3. It then negotiates the execution of the test methods and captures the test results using remote communication with the server.
   4. Finally, Arquillian undeploys the test archive.